# Mongoid date_select and validates_presence_of

Tags: validation, date, mongoid

So if I use `date_select` in the form and make the model `validates_presence_of :date`. I will get an error saying : Date can't be blank, even though I have chosen a date already.

```
  # in the form
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  # in the model
  validates_presence_of :date
```

I have read that mongoid has a problem with `date_select` in railscast mongoid screencast, however, it's an old tutorial, so I'm not sure if the problem still exist because I can't seem to find a solution online.

If I use `text_field` , the validation doesn't work at all. I can press submit without putting any date and will be redirect to an error page instead of a proper red warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To make date_select work with mongoid, I have to include

```
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
```

in the model class. Then in the controller you I have to handle the breakup of the date parameter. It came in 3 parts.

```
"date(1i)"=>"2013", "date(2i)"=>"5", "date(3i)"=>"26"
```

so I have to do

```
date = Date.new(params_apt['date(1i)'].to_i, params_apt['date(2i)'].to_i, params_apt['date(3i)'].to_i)
```

and you that `date` variable.

Comment: Only works with old versions of Mongoid. Learn more [here](https://github.com/netguru/mongoid-sadstory)